# Should Token created when the user registers or login?

Tags: javascript, api, react-native, https, token

I have an API created by one of my team :),

And he made an endpoints "Register/Login"

his thought

When user create a user we save his data and the endpoint response it **" without generating a Token"**

so i can't navigate him to other screens cuz I make a request based on his Token,

So he wants me to navigate user after register to the login screen then Login endpoint will response the **Token**

But I think it's not a nice way and not improve UX.

So what you think we do?

generate Token in the register or log in?

Comment: Sometime in the future, you (and your team) may implement email confirmation. Which then will make the token generation on signup kinda useless. I think to generate on login the best way to go.

Comment: @dheemonk hmmm, I don't think about this before

Answer (score 1):

The way I see this:

**Solution 1:**

You have him change the register API so that returns a token for you and you keep doing whatever you do with it.

**Solution 2:**

By registering, I'm assuming they type in a username/email, some personal details and a password!? So you have all the data to log the user in after registration. Upon successful registration, use the same username/email and password from memory (do not store them in browser storage) and call the login api to get the token (you only redirect after you've gotten the token) - so UX doesn't suffer here.

---

P.S. Instead of "fighting" one another over who's solution is better, try to work together in a solution. This is clearly an "I told you so" attempt - hence why I gave you two solution where both sides can do the work. Both of you can implement a solution without affecting UX, it's a matter of who's more stubborn :P

Comment: Very well, but if we go with the second solution How can i Get the password if i don't save it before? I work on Mobile stuff, not browser :)) and Register/Login in a separate screen :D

Comment: Your tags say: Javascript, api, https, jwt, token :P either way, as I said, you can store it in MEMORY and access it later - which you can do with any language. You don't have to use the Login screen, you can use the LOGIN API from the Register page.

Comment: I don't downvote i swear :( Great I will discuss it with backend Dev